# Internet not reachable from the terminal in kali linux 2.0

Tags: kali-linux, proxy

I am running Kali Linux 2.0 in virtual machine in windows 8.1.The problem here is my terminal is not connecting to the internet, but my kali linux browser is working perfectly.

I could not use tools like "sqlmap". I also cannot update my packages.

I have faced the same problem while using Linux Mint 17.1.

*One important point is that I live in my college hostel, so I use a LAN to access the internet which is configured with a proxy.*

Answer (score 1):

You said it all in your final note: the goal of a proxy if precisely to prevent you to connect directly to the Internet and limit your possible actions only to the ones allowed by the applicable local policy (ie. you college hostel Internet usage policy).

So, if you want to try out Kali Linux tools, you have two choices:

- Either circumvent the proxy limitations, which is most probably against the above mentioned applicable policy and may therefore bring in hot water very quickly,
- Or install a second system, like a second VM on your machine, containing an OS specially crafted to learn penetration testing software usage (search for "damn vulnerable" on the web to find some). This is the legit, trouble-free and recommended way to proceed.

Moreover, as you were beginning to try to proceed to test your tools against live systems on the Internet, I suppose that you chose systems specially crafted for such studies? I said so because it would not be very legal too to wander around on the Internet trying to apply your automated hacking tools on random websites...

Comment: Can you please help me with the first method  i.e, circumventing the proxy limitations cause i desparately need this kali terminal to work.

Comment: If you have legitimate reasons you can expose them to your network/proxy administrators or college hostel management. They should be able to whitelist your computer (based on its MAC address for instance) to provide you an unfiltered access to the Internet (but this might not be always possible though, it depends on the software they use, etc.).

Comment: then why is terminal showing an internet address and a subnet mask when i type the command "ifconfig -a".Doesn't that mean i have a internet connection?.I am able to browse through iceweasel freely.I have all the required information like "proxy" and "port" which was provided by the administrator.So why on earth only terminal is not working.Basic commands like /* ping www.google.com */ are also not working and giving me an error like ping: unknown host www.google.com

Comment: Because, unlike command-line tools, the browser is delegating all the work to the proxy (including name resolution) which really acts as a relay between your browser and Internet. The fact that you have an IP address and DNS mask only shows that you are correctly connected to a network (here the LAN), but not that you have any direct Internet connectivity.

Comment: can you suggest me an OS other than kali linux for penetration testing which is vulnerable as you said

Comment: You can give a try to [Metasploitable 2](http://r-7.co/Metasploitable2) or [Web Security Dojo](https://www.mavensecurity.com/web_security_dojo/) which seem to provide valuable projects with good documentation to learn how to proceed. You can also find other suggestions on [IT Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/57950/32746) and on the [OWASP Website](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Vulnerable_Web_Applications_Directory_Project).